# Resize the images?

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, nivo-slider

I have some images:

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/3.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/4.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/5.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Basically they have size around 600x450. And I applied CSS to them.

```
.nivoSlider img
{
   height: 450px;
   width: 600px;
   margin-left: 25px;
}
```

I wanted to make a slide show then I selected nivoSlider plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({
            effect: 'random', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
            slices: 15, // For slice animations
            boxCols: 8, // For box animations
            boxRows: 4, // For box animations
            animSpeed: 300, // Slide transition speed
            pauseTime: 3000, // How long each slide will show
            startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
            directionNav: true, // Next & Prev navigation
            controlNav: true, // 1,2,3... navigation
            controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
            pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
            manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
            prevText: '<<', // Prev directionNav text
            nextText: '>>', // Next directionNav text
            randomStart: false, // Start on a random slide
            beforeChange: function () { }, // Triggers before a slide transition
            afterChange: function () { }, // Triggers after a slide transition
            slideshowEnd: function () { }, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
            lastSlide: function () { }, // Triggers when last slide is shown
            afterLoad: function () { } // Triggers when slider has loaded
        });
```

My question is how to change the size dynamically when browser width changing?

Comment: have you heared about responsive webdesign? :) http://designmodo.com/responsive-design-examples/

Comment: nivoSlider should be responsive, I guess you should look over [their documentation](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/#/documentation) to implement it correctly.

Comment: Yes, my bad, it supports responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this slider... it is full responsive and easy editable :)

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Answer (score 0):

Target `window`'s resizing function.

```
window.onresize = function() {
    document.getElementByTagName('img').style.width -= "5px"; //decrease it every time
    document.getElementByTagName('img').style.height -= "5px"; //decrease it every time
}
```

Read more about `onresize` @ [`window.onresize` : MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onresize).

*As a side note, I gave a pure JS solution so that load on your server could not increase. :)*